# How can I calculate this integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Can someone please explain how to calculate this integral. I'm pretty sure you have to use the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus but I can't figure out how:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{3} \,dx  $$

Comment: There is a mistake in your question. The symbol $x$ has no meaning outside of the integral

Comment: It's zero, should the integral converge (it does).

Comment: It's a definite integral so the value of the integral is just some number. In particular, it is constant. Therefore, the derivative is ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x3$ is continuous and hence integrable on $[0,\frac{\pi}2]$, so the integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x3dx$$
exists.

Let the value of the integral be $I$. The whole expression becomes
$$\frac{d}{dx}I$$
which obviously evaluates to zero.